# Characteristic function of an r.v. with finite variance and zero mean.

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Suppose $E{|X|^{2}}<\infty$ and $E{X}=0$. Show that Var(X)$= \sigma^{2}<\infty$ (done), and that $\varphi_{X}(u)=1-\frac{1}{2}u^{2}\sigma^{2}+o(u^{2})$ (what I can't figure out how to find, especially since we're not given a distribution).

I'm really at my wits' end; please help!

Also, FYI: a function is $o(t)$ if $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|g(t)|}{t}=0$.

Comment: Hint: $\varphi(u) = E\left[e^{iuX}\right] = E[1 + iuX + (iuX)^2/2! + \cdots] = 1 + iuE[X] - \frac{1}{2}u^2E[X^2] + \cdots$

Comment: Ooh. Power series! Nice! Thanks :)

Comment: As far as the conditions that allow us to apply linearity of the expectation to an infinite sum the same way we would a finite sum?

Comment: Also, I'm having trouble that the remaining terms are $o(u^{2})$ using the definition I provided above.

Answer (score 2):

As a consequence of Taylor's formula, we have for each $x$ the inequality 
$$\left|e^{ix}-1+ix-\frac{x^2}2\right|\leqslant\min\left\{\frac{|x|^3}6,\frac{2x^2}2\right\}.$$
Using this with $x=u\cdot X(\omega)$, we have 
\begin{align}
|\varphi(u)|&\leqslant \mathbb E\left[1-iX+\frac{X^2}2\right]+
\mathbb E\left[\min\left\{\frac{u^3|X|^3}6,\frac{2X^2u^2}2\right\}\right]\\
&=1-\frac{\sigma^2}2u^2+\mathbb E\left[\min\left\{\frac{|X|^3u^3}6,\frac{2X^2u^2}2\right\}\right].
\end{align}
It thus remains to show that 
$$\lim_{u\to 0}\mathbb E\left[\min\left\{\frac{|X|^3u}6,\frac{2X^2}2\right\}\right]=0,$$
which is a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem.